# Extended Real Unit Interval Bijection

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

How can the unit interval, $I=[0,1]$ and extended reals, $[-\infty,\infty]$, be homeomorphic when there is no arithmetic operator to go from infinity to one, even though one times infinity equals infinity, so infinity is an open set in extended real topological space, ( X = $[-\infty,\infty]$ , discrete topology where any subset is an open set ), but its preimage in unit interval topological space, ( X = [0, 1] , discrete topology ), is not.

Comment: If you can believe that $(0,1)$ and $\mathbb R$ are homeomorphic, which hopefully is clear, then you have your answer.

Answer (score 1):

> when there is no arithmetic operator to go from infinity to one

It's true that there is no [*rational* function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function) $f$ having the property that $\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=1$ and $\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=0$. So simple "arithmetic operators" won't get the job done. On the other hand, consider the [logistic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function)...

> infinity is an open set in extended real topological space

The singleton set $\{+\infty\}$ is closed, not open, in $[-\infty,+\infty]$. Just as $\{1\}$ is closed, not open, in $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

If you believe that the open interval is homeomorphic to the line, this shouldn't be too much of a stretch to believe. Just extend the homeomorphism to the endpoints, and check that this is continuous. If you take an open set containing $\pm \infty$, the preimage ought to be an open set containing either $0$ or $1$, respectively. This is open in the subspace topology on $[0,1]$ though, and vice-versa for the inverse map.

Maybe you think that a homeomorphism has to be written down in terms of elementary functions or by some explicit formula. This definitely isn't true.  All the time in topology we consider blobs that are homeomorphic without question. Just take any two simple closed curves in the plane. The interior of the regions they bound are both homeomorphic to a disk, but there's not going to be any formula for those curves, let alone a map that you can easily check to be a homeomorphism taking one to the other.

Answer (score 1):

Convince yourself that $(0,1) \simeq \mathbb{R}$. Now $[0,1]$ is the unique (up to linear homeomorphism) ordered compactification of $(0,1)$ and the extended reals $[-\infty, +\infty]$ are the same for $\mathbb{R}$.